# TypeError: argument of type 'char const *'

Tags: python, freeswitch

I'm currently working with Freeswitch and its [event socket library](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_Socket_Library) (through the [mod event socket](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_event_socket)).  For instance:

```
from ESL import ESLconnection

cmd = 'uuid_kill %s' % active_call # active_call comes from a Django db and is unicode
con = ESLconnection(config.HOST, config.PORT, config.PWD)
if con.connected():
    e = con.api(str(cmd))
else:
    logging.error('Couldn\'t connect to Freeswitch Mod Event Socket')
```

As you can see, I had to explicitly cast `con.api()`'s argument with `str()`.  Without that, the call ends up in the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
    e = con.api(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ESL.py", line 87, in api
    def api(*args): return apply(_ESL.ESLconnection_api, args)
TypeError: in method 'ESLconnection_api', argument 2 of type 'char const *'
```

I don't understand this TypeError: what does it mean ?  `cmd` contains a string, so what does it fix it when I cast it with `str(cmd)` ?
Could it be related to Freeswitch's python API, generated through [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) ?

Comment: What is the type of `active_call`? If it is unicode, then `cmd` will be a Unicode string, and `str(cmd)` will convert it to string. You can insert an `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` line before the `con.api` call, and inspect `cmd`.

Comment: `active_call` is most probably unicode, indeed (comes out of a Django database), but there is nothing in this error message that makes me think about unicode: do you think it might be related ?

Comment: It's certainly related: the API is likely exported through an interface-building framework that only knows how to convert Python string objects to `char const *` (by calling `PyString_AsString` on the object). Python 2 Unicode strings do not consist of C chars — they consist of `wchar_t`, which means they cannot be trivially "cast" to `const char *`, they need to be converted into a new buffer, which must be allocated, etc. By pre-converting the Unicode string to string in Python, you perform the hard part before the object ever reaches C.

Comment: Mhmmm, that would be consistent with some of the FS's python files, mentioning *SWIG* (http://www.swig.org), which describes itself as *a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages*.  There still are some things I don't know about, like what's a `char const *`, a `C char` or a `wchar_t`, but imo your comment definitely deserves to be an answer.  Please feel free to provide more tech details if you are in the mood ;)  (Also I'll add details to my question)

Comment: I wasn't aware you weren't aware of C fundamentals. :) I've now added an answer that explains this in some detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great details and this excellent reminder of C fundamentals (yeah, I forgot most of it over time, not proud about that...)  Sad I can't upvote more than once !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer: `cmd` likely contains a Unicode string, which cannot be trivially converted to a `const char *`. The error message might come from a wrapper framework that automates writing Python bindings for C libraries, such as SWIG or ctypes. The framework knows what to do with a byte string, but punts on Unicode strings. Passing `str(cmd)` helps because it converts the Unicode string to a byte string, from which a `const char *` value expected by C code can be trivially extracted.

Long answer:

The C type `char const *`, more customarily spelled `const char *`, can be read as "read-only array of `char`", `char` being C's way to spell "byte". When a C function accepts a `const char *`, it expects a "C string", i.e. an array of `char` values terminated with a null character. Conveniently, Python strings are internally represented as C strings with some additional information such as type, reference count, and the length of the string (so the string length can be retrieved with O(1) complexity, and also so that the string may contain null characters themselves).

Unicode strings in Python 2 are represented as arrays of `Py_UNICODE`, which are either 16 or 32 bits wide, depending on the operating system and build-time flags. Such an array cannot be passed to code that expects an array of 8-bit chars — it needs to be *converted*, typically to a temporary buffer, and this buffer must be freed when no longer needed.

For example, a simple-minded (and quite unnecessary) wrapper for the C function `strlen` could look like this:

```
PyObject *strlen(PyObject *ignore, PyObject *obj)
{
  if (!PyString_Check(obj)) {
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "string expected, got %s", Py_TYPE(obj)->tp_name);
    return NULL;
  }
  const char *c_string = PyString_AsString(obj);
  size_t len = strlen(c_string);
  return PyInt_FromLong((long) len);
}
```

The code simply calls `PyString_AsString` to retrieve the internal C string stored by every Python string and expected by `strlen`. For this code to also support Unicode objects (provided it even makes sense to call `strlen` on Unicode objects), it must handle them explicitly:

```
PyObject *strlen(PyObject *ignore, PyObject *obj)
{
  const char *c_string;
  PyObject *tmp = NULL;
  if (PyString_Check(obj))
    c_string = PyString_AsString(obj);
  else if (PyUnicode_Check(obj)) {
    if (!(tmp = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(obj)))
      return NULL;
    c_string = PyString_AsString(tmp);
  }
  else {
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "string or unicode expected, got %s",
                 Py_TYPE(obj)->tp_name);
    return NULL;
  }
  size_t len = strlen(c_string);
  Py_XDECREF(tmp);
  return PyInt_FromLong((long) len);
}
```

Note the additional complexity, not only in lines of boilerplate code, but in the different code paths that require different management of a temporary object that holds the byte representation of the Unicode string. Also note that the code needed to decide to on an *encoding* when converting a Unicode string to a byte string. UTF-8 is guaranteed to be able to encode any Unicode string, but passing a UTF-8-encoded sequence to a function expecting a C string might not make sense for some uses. The `str` function uses the ASCII codec to encode the Unicode string, so if the Unicode string actually contained any non-ASCII characters, you would get an exception.

There have been [requests to include this functionality in SWIG](http://sourceforge.net/p/swig/feature-requests/75/), but it is unclear from the linked report if they made it in.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, and I solved it by doing this:

`cmd = 'uuid_kill %s'.encode('utf-8')`